# How do I retrieve a full listing of AWS cloud services products with descriptions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

> tl;dr: I just want a simple way to retrieve AWS cloud services product names and descriptions. Please help me, I am clearly missing something.

This task seemed so simple at first but has ballooned into a whole ordeal, and I am struggling to understand how it's possible it's this difficult.

### The goal: to get a simple list of all the AWS cloud services with their friendly descriptions

#### Option 1: AWS CLI

I would prefer to use the AWS CLI for this task, but it doesn't seem possible. If I type `aws <tab>` it autocompletes a full list of service names but there is no way to retrieve the friendly descriptions of the corresponding services.

#### Option 2: Scrape `aws.amazon.com/products`

This is a no-go without lots of effort, as AWS has added pagination to the list on this page. Any automated scrape would require me to find the navigation buttons and iterate, scrape, iterate, scrape, etc. Really irritating. Though I need to check the source to see if they're at least loaded in the DOM even if it's paginated, as that would make it easier.

[image: Official product page, paginated]

#### Option 3: Scrape the page in its more usefully-formatted form at `amazonaws.cn/en/products`

Another scrape required, but at least this is not paginated and is more accessible. The primary problem is that since it's China there are only ~100 of the 228 services available, so the majority are missing.

[image: Chinese products page, non-paginated]

#### Option 4: Use other people's incomplete lists

I found this website (https://www.eckher.com/c/21gjdl7gz4) (I know the link looks crazy but it is real and not crazy). It's a noble effort but is missing many of the service descriptions.

[image: Incomplete descriptions from someone's web site]

#### Other

I found this dead GitHub repo which was promising but is broken: [`palsarma/aws_products`](https://github.com/palsarma/aws_products)

I am *really* hoping someone here has figured out how to do this, it would be really excellent to have this problem solved so I can move on with my life.

Thank you for reading, if you are still here.

Comment: Would some parsing of `aws help` and `aws <service> help` get what you're after?

Comment: There is no AWS api. You can scrape all names from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/.

Comment: I was about to write a reply, but @Anon Coward put it as a comment. It's not so complex, actually. First, run `aws help` and capture everything after "Available Services" through "See Also". Then remove asterisk and space, and run `aws $1 help` and get description. You can use bash script, powershell, probably sed - or any language with good line processing capabilties

Comment: Can you tell us _WHY_ you want this list? The definition of an "AWS service" can vary depending upon your actual need. For example, Amazon EBS can only be used with Amazon EC2. So, is it a separate "service"? Please tell us more about how you'll be using this list.

Comment: Or, you could [parse the data out of the source code](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/9a2c44317a04cb737b98fa19a0539e20) of the botocore help system.  Pretty much whatever you do will require some human editing of the text, though.